# JavaFX stress test failed

Tags: javafx, stress-testing, resource-leak

We are looking into JavaFX 2.2 as a framework for building a desktop application. But before burning many developer hours we wanted to make sure that JavaFX is fit for the job, so we made a small stress test to see if it leaks resources. The test shows and hides a Stage, containing a Label and a Button, in a never ending loop. We would expect this to continue forever without problems, but after approx 15500 iterations we get this exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: could not create platform window
at com.sun.glass.ui.Window.<init>(Window.java:180)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindow.<init>(WinWindow.java:20)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.createWindow(WinApplication.java:97)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.initPlatformWindow(WindowStage.java:131)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.WindowStage.init(WindowStage.java:82)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createTKStage(QuantumToolkit.java:501)
at javafx.stage.Stage.impl_visibleChanging(Stage.java:928)
at javafx.stage.Window$10.invalidated(Window.java:689)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:127)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:161)
at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:782)
at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:797)
at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:229)
at leaktest.FXMLController.showHideDialog(FXMLController.java:58)
```

Our best guess is that show()/hide() on Stage leaks some resource, and dheapmon reveals that desktop heap memory is actually leaked during the test, but we don't hit the limit (20 MB on our test machine). GDI handle and USER handle limits are not the problem either since those handles are not leaked (according to Process explorer). Any suggestions to what causes the exception?

Comment: Can you share the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

This was a memory leak in the window disposal code of JavaFX.  The leak was fixed in JavaFX 2.2.40 as part of bug fix [RT-26822 Win: Stage Exception:could not create platform window](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-26822).